# not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, ssl, smtplib

i am stacked with the following problem and I dont know how to sole it. Please help, would be nice if you could also explain how you did it.

```
 import csv, smtplib, ssl
 
 message = """Subject: Your grade
 
 Hi {name}, your grade is {grade}"""
 from_address = "michael@gmail.com"
 password = input("Type your password and press enter: ")
 
 context = ssl.create_default_context()
 with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
     server.login(from_address, password)
     with open("contacts_file.csv") as file:
         reader = csv.reader(file)
         next(reader)  # Skip header row
         for name, email, grade in reader:
             server.sendmail(
                 from_address,
                 email,
                 message.format(name=name,grade=grade),
             )
```

EROR

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/var/folders/q8/qn3d11d90fbbz0j6kllhpn9h0000gn/T/ipykernel_34629/2824055323.py in <module>
     13         reader = csv.reader(file)
     14         next(reader)  # Skip header row
---> 15         for name, email, grade in reader:
     16             server.sendmail(
     17                 from_address,

ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)
```

Comment: What does the file look like? The error is telling you there is only one field in the row.

Comment: name;email;grade
michael;y@gmail.com;2
zas;s@gmail.com;32
dasdas;btnike888@vireonidae.com;32
dasdas;ym2000@gmail.com;312

Comment: Do you get the error immediately after the header is read, or after the last row has been read, or somewhere in between? I suspect an empty line in your file.

Comment: You need to set the delimiter `reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')`.  The default delimiter for csv files is a comma, not a semi-colon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your main issue is that your file is semi-colon delimited, and the CSV reader expects the file to be comma delimited.

Here's what you have now:

```py
with open('contacts_file.csv') as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file)
    next(reader)  # Skip header row
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

and that looks like this:

```py
['michael;y@gmail.com;2']
['zas;s@gmail.com;32']
['dasdas;btnike888@vireonidae.com;32']
['dasdas;ym2000@gmail.com;312']
```

Your rows are a list of one string, and that's causing your "unpack error": you're expecting each row (list) to contain three items, but right now there's only item: the entire row.

Specify the delimiter:

```py
reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=';')
```

and you'll get:

```py
['michael', 'y@gmail.com', '2']
['zas', 's@gmail.com', '32']
['dasdas', 'btnike888@vireonidae.com', '32']
['dasdas', 'ym2000@gmail.com', '312']
```

and now you can unpack each row:

```py
for row in reader:
    name, email, grade = row
    ...
```

I recommend reading `row` as whole thing, then unpacking `row`.  It's easier to check for correctness and debug:

```py
for row in reader:
    assert len(row) == 3, f'Expected 3 columns but only have {len(row)}: {row}'
    name, email, grade = row
```

For your original setup you'd get a helpful error like:

```
AssertionError: Expected 3 columns but only have 1: ['michael;y@gmail.com;2']
```